# Objective C: Score Counter

Tags: objective-c, ios

i'm trying to come up with a simple game on iOS and i's stuck in getting the scores.

here's what i did.

in every correct button combinations i put this

```
ctr = ctr + 1
```

then here

```
    - (void) scorer
       {
            if (ctr == 9)
                {
                     [winner setHidden:NO];
                }
       }
```

i am trying this code but it is not working...
what's wrong?

my deadline is coming i hope i could finish this early, i know it's quite simple.

thanks in advance!

Comment: do you call `scorer` after increasing ctr value?

Comment: You need to add some more info. What is not working? What is winner, a NSTextField? How are you calling scorer? Have you logged ctr to make sure it is getting to 9?

Comment: put an NSLog to make sure to enters the function.  Is ctr accessible?  is winner accessible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after

```
ctr=ctr+1
```

you should call

```
[self scorer]
```

and you should try putting a NSLog in scorer inside and outside of the If statement so you can be sure it is being executed as expected.